# Force PrintDocumentAdapter.onLayout() call when advancedPrintOptionsActivity made changes

Tags: android, printing, service

This looks to me as a bug in the Android printing subsystem but I'd like to know if somebody has a workaround.

Suppose we have a `PrintService` installed that advertises an `advancedPrintOptionsActivity` in its resource file. During the printing operation, this activity is called when the user selects the *More options* item from the UI. When finished, the activity duly creates a new `PrintJobInfo` based on the original `EXTRA_PRINT_JOB_INFO` from the intent, adding its own advanced options to the mix, and sets it as its own result.

As the new settings in the advanced options activity might (and probably will) influence how the document is laid out, the system should now call the `onLayout()` of the `PrintDocumentAdapter` for a new PDF, as it always does when attributes are changed in its own UI. But this doesn't happen: either because it's simply omitted or because it doesn't see any changes in the attributes and doesn't feel the call necessary.

How can we force the printing service to call a new `onLayout()` cycle in this case?

(Addendum: yes, if the user finally sends the print job, the advanced options set on `EXTRA_PRINT_JOB_INFO` are present and passed along, meaning that the actual print can use the settings. Still, they don't show up in the UI *before* committing to print, meaning that what the user sees and what they finally get might well be different.)